# Transclude extra mat-tab into mat-tab-group doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-material, transclusion

I have a Component `CreateEditPersonComponent` for editing personal information. The personal information are organized in material design tabs this way:

```
<mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab label="Personal Info">
        --- Personal info ---
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Address">
        --- Address info ---
      </mat-tab>
      <ng-content></ng-content>  <- ADDITIONAL TABS WOULD BE ADDED HERE.
</mat-tab-group>
```

I have another component `CreateEditPatientComponent` which takes the `CreateEditPersonComponent` and it supposes to add a tab with the Patients related information (Medical Records, ...).

```
<create-edit-person> <-- CREATE / EDIT PERSON COMPONENT. 
  <mat-tab label="Medical Records"> <-- IT SUPPOSES TO APPEND A NEW TAB TO THE MAT TAB GROUP.
    <div>
      --- Medical Records ---
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</create-edit-person>
```

The point is, this code runs with no errors and shows up the Personal information form as long as the address information but the patient related tab is not rendered.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The way mat-tab-group gets its mat-tabs is through `@ContentChildren(MatTab)`, only looking for MatTab. `ng-content` in `mat-tab-group` is not a MatTab, so it is ignored.

We can hack it in your 'CreateEditPersonComponent':

```
{
  @ViewChild(MatTabGroup) matTabGroup: MatTabGroup;
  @ViewChildren(MatTab) inclusiveTabs: QueryList<MatTab>;
  @ContentChildren(MatTab, {descendants: true}) tabsFromNgContent: QueryList<MatTab>;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.matTabGroup._tabs.reset([...this.inclusiveTabs.toArray(), ...this.tabsFromNgContent.toArray()]);
    this.matTabGroup._tabs.notifyOnChanges();
  }
}
```